# parseError when running Python script from node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pandas, express

I am constructing a movie recommender. My recommender engine is written in Python. And I am running it from website through node.js (Express).

The python code itselfs work and here is the output when I am running it from a console. It is using pandas and numpy for calculations it returns a matrix with title of movie and its similarity to a chosen movie, and I also print hello:

[Python command code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8JVI.png)

On my website I have following **HTML** in body:

```
<form class="test" method="post" action="/test">
   <input type="text" name="user[name]">
   <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JS** Client side

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function () {
      var btn = $('.button'),
          input = $('input');
      btn.on('click', function() {
        e.preventDefault();
      })
  })
})(jQuery)
```

**JS** server side, with **Express**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
  mode: 'text',
  pythonOptions: ['-u'],
  scriptPath: "E:/Praca Magisterska/Python",
};

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
})

app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  PythonShell.run('similarMovies.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
    console.log('results: %j', results);
  });

})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

So, how it works. On clicking submit btn I am firing my node.js to run a python script and then `console.log` the results. Unfortunately I am getting errors, image at the end.

However, when I do not run function and instead of it I  write at the end of my Python just:

```
print "hello"
print 2
```

the results of code are parsed good.

[Image of command an results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0wPT.png)

What could be an issue? Erros that I am getting with dividing by zero and other inside a funcion? But if yes why then it is working when I run it directly from cmd - `python similarMovies.py`

Here is **python** code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def showSimilarMovies(movieTitle, minRatings):

        # import ratingów z pliku csv
    rating_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating']
    rating = pd.read_csv('E:/Praca Magisterska/MovieLens Data/ratings.csv', names = rating_cols, usecols = range(3))

    # import filmów z pliku csv
    movie_cols = ['movie_id', 'title']
    movie = pd.read_csv('E:/Praca Magisterska/MovieLens Data/movies.csv', names = movie_cols, usecols = range(2))

    # łączenie zaimportowanych ratingów oraz filmów, usuwanie pierwszego wiersza
    ratings = pd.merge(movie, rating)
    ratings = ratings.drop(ratings.index[[0]])
    # konwertowanie kolumn ze stringów na numeric
    ratings['rating'] = pd.to_numeric(ratings['rating'])
    ratings['user_id'] = pd.to_numeric(ratings['user_id'])

    # tworzenie macierzy pokazująceje oceny filmów przez wszystkich użytkowników.
    movieRatingsPivot = ratings.pivot_table(index=['user_id'], columns=['title'], values='rating')

    # filtrowanie kolumny do  obliczania filmów podobnych
    starWarsRating = movieRatingsPivot[movieTitle]

    # obliczanie korelacji danego filmu z każdym innym i wyrzucanie tych z którymi nic go nie łączy
    similarMovies = movieRatingsPivot.corrwith(starWarsRating)
    similarMovies = pd.DataFrame(similarMovies.dropna())

    # zmiana nazwy kolumny oraz sortowanie według rosnącej korelacji
    similarMovies.columns = ['similarity']
    similarMovies.sort_values(by=['similarity'], ascending=False)

    # tworzenie statystyk dla filmów, size to ilość ocen, a mean to średnia z ocen
    # zgrupowane po tytułach
    movieStats = ratings.groupby('title').agg({'rating': [np.size, np.mean]})

    # popularne filmy, które mają więcej niż 100 ocen
    popularMovies = movieStats['rating']['size']>=minRatings

    # sortowanie popularnych filmów od najwyższej średniej
    movieStats[popularMovies].sort_values(by=[('rating', 'mean')], ascending=False)

    # łączenie popularnych filmów z filmami podobnymi do  filtrowanego filmu i ich sortowanie
    moviesBySimilarity = movieStats[popularMovies].join(similarMovies)
    x = moviesBySimilarity.sort_values(by='similarity', ascending=False)
    k = x.drop(x.columns[[0, 1]], axis = 1)
    k = k.drop(x.index[[0]])
    return k

print "hello"    
print 2
showSimilarMovies('Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)', 300)
```

Comment: Consider wrapping `showSimilarMovies` call in something like `try ... except BaseException as e: with open("error.txt", "w") as f: f.write(repr(e))`. The idea is to log exception somewhere, so you can see what exactly had crashed.

Comment: @drdaeman
hey, I tried:
`with open("error.txt", "w") as f: 
    try:
        showSimilarMovies('Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)', 300) 
    except BaseException as e: 
        f.write(repr(e))`
Unfortunately error.txt is empty. When I tried Yours version it did not even created an error.txt

Comment: Hey, when I commented in function showSimilarMovies everything to - line `starWarsRating = movieRatingsPivot[movieTitle]` and printed this variable as an ouput from a function everything is okay.
So python Shell parser is somehow ending script due to warnings from numpy and pandas, which are shown in image of command and results, how can I ignore those erros and tell node to just run the script to the end?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, just added two lines at the beggining of python file to ignore warnings:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Now my output is what was desired.