# Opencv error init done

Tags: python, node.js, opencv

I have been running python script with nodejs using python-shell package.. and i am getting this error:

```
Error: init done

at PythonShell.parseError (F:\github\pythonShellDemo\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:191:17)
at terminateIfNeeded (F:\github\pythonShellDemo\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:98:28)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (F:\github\pythonShellDemo\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:89:9)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

after some debugging and research i got to know that this error is with opencv but i cant find any solution..

here is the code:

```
import cv2
import zbar
from PIL import Image
import sys

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count=0
qrcode=[]
while True:
  ret, frame = video.read()
  cv2.imshow('Camera', frame)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
  grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  image = Image.fromarray(grayscale)
  width, height = image.size
  zbarimage = zbar.Image(width, height,'Y800', image.tobytes())
  scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
  scanner.scan(zbarimage)
  for x in zbarimage:
    if count == 0:
      qrcode=x.data
      count=count+1
  if qrcode:
    break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(qrcode)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I am using python 2.7

UPDATE: 
nodejs code for calling python script:

```
PythonShell.run('python/scan.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    reject(err)
  }
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
  console.log(results)
  resolve(results)
})
```

UPDATE: 
i tried running opencv only without zbar.. still got the error

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does that script run correctly on its own? Does it output anything like that "init done" error message? Maybe it's just [some warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822389/parseerror-when-running-python-script-from-node-js) that you could disable (Doesn't look like anything I've seen OpenCV output, maybe `zbar` does it)? Otherwise, reduce that script to [MCVE] that still reproduces the error, and update your question.

Comment: @DanMašek yes it runs perfectly on its own.. and i have tried disabling that warnings but no success

Comment: @DanMašek i tried removing opencv code and running the script with everything same.. it runs perfectly with no error..

Comment: @DanMašek i have updated my question

Comment: Cool, you're down to two possible culprits here, I guess -- either the `VideoCapture`, or the highgui code (`imshow` and related). Try to reduce a bit further ;) | BTW, where is this code running when you call it from node.js? Just asking since sometimes people try to use highgui on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV library prints `init done` to the standard error output.  It's not an error, but just a debug print.  `python-shell` then turns this into an error.  From the `python-shell` documentation:

> If the script writes to stderr or exits with a non-zero code, an error will be thrown.

Suppressing the output seems to be only possible by [recompiling the library with a parameter set](http://answers.opencv.org/question/91423/supressing-init-done-and-opengl-support-available/).

Comment: Interesting. What platform is this on, using which highgui backend? E.g. I've yet to see this happen on windows. | However if output to stderr is fatal, then OpenCV may be a problem, since even caught and handled exceptions end up printing to stderr (there will be a way to avoid that in the next release).